# Java reading file and do different function

Tags: java

I have the textfile as follow, it has 2 section PLUS and MINUS and 2 question in each section. I would want to write a program to solve them. I attached my code below as I could not get to the MINUS potion. The result I got for Minus is still using Plus operator.

math.txt

```
[Plus]
Question = 0
num1 = 2
num2 = 3

Question = 1
num1 = 4
num2 = 5

[Minus]
Question = 0
num2 = 6
num1 = 5

Question = 1
num2 = 7
num1 = 2
```

CODE
:

```
BufferedReader in = null;
InputStream fis;

try {
    fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
    String line = null;

    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {

        String[] file_Array = line.split(" = ");

        if (file_Array[0].equalsIgnoreCase("num1")) {
            num1 = file_Array[1];

        } else if (file_Array[0].equalsIgnoreCase("num2")) {
            num2 = file_Array[1];
            int sum = Integer.parseInt(num1) + Integer.parseInt(num2);

            System.out.println("Answer :" + sum);
        }                
        else if (file_Array[0].equalsIgnoreCase("[Minus]")) {

         if (file_Array[0].equalsIgnoreCase("num2")) {
            num2 = file_Array[1];
        } else if (file_Array[0].equalsIgnoreCase("num1")) {
            num1 = file_Array[1];
            int minus = Integer.parseInt(num2) - Integer.parseInt(num1);
            System.out.println("Answer :" + minus);
        } 
        }
    }

} catch (IOException ex) {
    System.out.println("Input file " + file + " not found");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

My solution is as below :

```
public static void main(String arg[]) {
    BufferedReader in = null;
    InputStream fis;
    String file = "math.txt";
    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
        String line = null;
        String section=null;
        String num1 = null;
        String num2 = null;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] file_Array = line.split(" = ");
            if (file_Array[0].equalsIgnoreCase("[Minus]"))
            {
                section="Minus";
            }
            if (file_Array[0].equalsIgnoreCase("[Plus]"))
            {
                section="Plus";
            }


            if (file_Array[0].equalsIgnoreCase("num1")) {
                num1 = file_Array[1];
            } else if (file_Array[0].equalsIgnoreCase("num2")) {
                num2 = file_Array[1];
            }
            //Solution depends on the fact that there will be a blank line
            //after operands.
            if (file_Array[0].equals("")){
                printResult(section,num1,num2);
            }
        }
        //There is no blank line at the end of the file, so call printResult again.
        printResult(section,num1,num2);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Input file " + file + " not found");
    }
}

private static void printResult(String section,String num1,String num2) {
    if (section.equals("Minus")){
         int minus = Integer.parseInt(num2) - Integer.parseInt(num1);
         System.out.println("Answer :" + minus);
    }
    if (section.equals("Plus")){
         int sum = Integer.parseInt(num1) + Integer.parseInt(num2);
         System.out.println("Answer :" + sum);
    }

}
```